# iOS app rejected due to unlocking content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

Recently, I finished developing an app in which users unlock resources using codes. These codes are free but users need an authorization from a contact to get them.

I had uploaded the app in iTunes-connect but now Apple said I must remove this feature from my app because it goes against 3.1.1 guidelines (In-app-purchase).

Reading this guideline, I found that:

> Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.

but, as I said (and I told it to Apple), I don't use any kind of purchase in my app nor out of it.

Is there anything I can do, as this feature is 100% of my app?

**Edit:**

I found this in the guidelines (this is my case, if we asume "purchased=free"):

> 3.1.3 Content-based “Reader” Apps: Apps may allow a user to access previously purchased content or subscriptions (specifically: magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, video, access to professional databases, VoIP, cloud storage, and approved services such as educational apps that manage student grades and schedules), provided the app does not direct users to a purchasing mechanism other than IAP.

so, can I use this to pass the review?

Comment: The Authorization you added is making them feel of external service been used other than IAP, if you can remove the authorization, it may pass the review.

Comment: That seems a good idea. Im gonna try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the resource in question is something used by your app. If so, you probably have to use another approach to unlock resources other than using codes. As the guideline said, anything used by the app must be brought within the app (IAP). Codes can come from anywhere such as your app, your website and social network. The latter two are obviously not in your app.

But after all, if you let the user to unlock **some part of your app**, you have to use IAP, otherwise apple would reject it.

Comment: Perhaps you´re right, but the guidelines (chapter 3) talk specifically about monetization and purchases, and this is not the case, as everything is free. This is what I wanna explain to Apple. By the way, what you say is how things should have been done (I was not aware of these guidelines...)

Comment: I think apple doesn't care about whether the code is free or not. They only care about whether your mechanism is external to their services.

Comment: The key is the second paragraph of the answer. After various conversations with Apple, the problem they see is that our content is free, everyone should be able to access it. Otherwise content should have a cost (IAP). I don't agree with this policy, as we work with grants, so content is free but only accesible to groups of users, but (even with this working in other platforms) we need to change it for Apple to be happy.

Comment: If your users need to login, you can unlock functionality based on their account without their notice.

Comment: It's not that easy... I can't store any kind of information that could identify a user, so I can't use the user/password approach, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @Javi_Swift , so finally what did you do ? I am also stuck with a similar use case.

Comment: @SumitAnantwar We had to send Apple documentation to prove what we were saying was true. I had to talk with an Apple contact via phone call to explain everything.

Comment: I've just hit a wall with Apple too. The phone call with the App Store Review representative did not help. In our case, we wanted to use a code to pair the companion app of our ERP-Software with the ERP itself, but somehow §3.1.4 gets in the way. I do not understand Apple's policy.

Comment: But what if an Offer based app is there which can be unlocked by a code which is managed universally for iOS, Android and Web Platform?

Answer (score 1):

3.1.4 Content Codes: Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc. In limited circumstances, such as when features are dependent upon specific hardware to function, the app may unlock that functionality without using in-app purchase (e.g. an astronomy app that adds features when synced with a telescope). App features that work in combination with an approved physical product (such as a toy) on an optional basis may unlock functionality without using IAP, provided that an IAP option is available as well. You may not, however, require users to purchase unrelated products or engage in advertising or marketing activities to unlock app functionality.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: With 3.1.3 you don't unlock some features or contents, there are no mecanism to unlock, you have just "access" previously purchased content or subscriptions.